# How to keep dry in the property method

Tags: ember.js

If I want to watch rounds and savingHoursPerRound,

I should put them into property,

is there anyway to auto-watch all variable in the function ?

```
  savingHoursPerYear:function(){
    return this.get("rounds")*this.get("savingHoursPerRound");
  }.property("rounds","savingHoursPerRound"),
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is going to be the cleanest way to execute this particular statement.

You can look at the list of `computed` functions which solve the most basic common computed properties quite simply.

[Click here and scroll down](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_computed_alias)